# can getText() method distort the input to a method?

Tags: java, jframe, gettext

I am making a user interface to let the user insert an identification number (variable name pNo). I am trying to read the inserted number from a JTextfield and then pass it to another method (`createCreditAccount()`) that is supposed to create an account for the user.

Problem is the method `createCreditAccount()` does not return an account number like its supposed to. Even though I am certain that there are matching id numbers in the system.

Can anybody tell me why I don't get expected output. The method `createCreditAccount()` does not return what it supposed to. It returns -1 which would be correct in the case where here were no clients with that id but i have created those. I have also created customers and accounts from my main method which works fine. For example:

```
 SubWindowBankContainer.getBank().createCustomer("john", "doe", "7239009");
 int accountID = 
 SubWindowBankContainer.getBank().createCreditAccount("7239009");
 String account = 
 SubWindowBankContainer.getBank().getAccount("7239009", accountID);
```

this example above works perfectly fine when called from main method but not from the actionlistener method.

So I don't think anything is wrong with `createCreditAccount()`, I think something is wrong I the `actionPerformed()`; but what?

I am leaning towards that the `getText()` is adding extra emptyspaces or something like that.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent creditAccButtonPressed){
        if (creditAccButtonPressed.getSource()==pNoButton){
            String pNo = pNoTextField.getText(); 
int creditAccountId = SubWindowBankContainer.getBank().createCreditAccount(pNo);
            
            String Account = SubWindowBankContainer.getBank().getAccount(pNo,creditAccountId);
            
            }
        }
```

Here's the method I am calling

```
public int createCreditAccount(String pNr) {
    
    int accountNr = -1;
    int pNoIndex = getIndexForPno(pNr);

    if (pNoIndex > -1) {// Om id-nummret finns ...
        allCustomers.get(pNoIndex).addToAccountsList(new CreditAccount());
        accountNr = Account.getLastAssignedAccountNumber();
        }
    return accountNr;

}
```

Comment: So what does createCreditAccount return? Is it -1? There really is not enough information and to much missing code to make even an educated guess of what is happening.

Comment: OH GOD SPIDERS, thanks for comment i have edited the question, hope its better this way.

Comment: Well, one way for the `createCreditAccount` method to return -1 would be if `getIndexForPno` returned something that is < 1. But since you didn't post that method (and everything related to understand exactly how this method works) I don't know why it would do that. If you suspect that the `getText()` method of the TextField doesn't return the right value why don't you add some logger output that logs what this method returns and what you actually pass as `pNr` into the `createCreditAccount` method to see if your suspicion is correct.